# Blacklisting a specific packages from updating using UnattendedUpgrades in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, unattended-upgrades

I am trying to prevent updates of few packages from updating automatically by unattended upgrades in Debian 12:

The part of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` for blacklisting by default is this:

```
// Python regular expressions, matching packages to exclude from upgrading
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    // The following matches all packages starting with linux-
//  "linux-";

    // Use $ to explicitely define the end of a package name. Without
    // the $, "libc6" would match all of them.
//  "libc6$";
//  "libc6-dev$";
//  "libc6-i686$";

    // Special characters need escaping
//  "libstdc\+\+6$";

    // The following matches packages like xen-system-amd64, xen-utils-4.1,
    // xenstore-utils and libxenstore3.0
//  "(lib)?xen(store)?";

    // For more information about Python regular expressions, see
    // https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
};
```

If I want to blacklist upgrading of specific package versions``

```
      - openvpn=2.6.3-1+deb12u1
      - docker-ce=5:24.0.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
      - docker-ce-cli=5:24.0.0-1~debian.12~bookworm
      - containerd.io
      - docker-buildx-plugin
      - docker-compose-plugin
```

Can this be done by uncommenting `//  "linux-";` and replacing with

```
"openvpn-";
"docker-";
"containerd.io$";
```

Additionally, I am confused as to what this line mean in the config file: Is it updating all packages or security related packages only? I want to update only security packages automatically.

```
    "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
```

Full snippet of the above:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        // Codename based matching:
        // This will follow the migration of a release through different
        // archives (e.g. from testing to stable and later oldstable).
        // Software will be the latest available for the named release,
        // but the Debian release itself will not be automatically upgraded.
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-proposed-updates";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename}-security,label=Debian-Security";

        // Archive or Suite based matching:
        // Note that this will silently match a different release after
        // migration to the specified archive (e.g. testing becomes the
        // new stable).
//      "o=Debian,a=stable";
//      "o=Debian,a=stable-updates";
//      "o=Debian,a=proposed-updates";
//      "o=Debian Backports,a=${distro_codename}-backports,l=Debian Backports";
};
```